# python tarfile recursive extract in memory

Tags: python

I have a tar file with that contains compressed tar files.  Like this:

```
gnomeAware@devserv:~$ tar tf test.tar
File1.tar.gz
File2.tar.gz
File3.tar.gz
File4.tar.gz
```

tarfile expects a string as the file to open.  Is there anyway to pass it a file object?

```
tar = tarfile.open('test.tar', 'r') # Unpack tar
for item in tar:
  Bundle=tar.extractfile(item) # Pull out the file
  t = tarfile.open(Bundle, "r:gz") # Unpack tar
  for tItem in t:
  ...
```

Thanks.

Comment: From [`tarfile.open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.open): _"If fileobj is specified, it is used as an alternative to a file object opened in binary mode for name. It is supposed to be at position 0."_. `tar.extractfile(fileobj=Bundle, mode="r:gz")`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the definition of tarfile.open looks like this
`def open(cls, name=None, mode="r", fileobj=None, bufsize=RECORDSIZE, **kwargs):`

And python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.open) says that

> If fileobj is specified, it is used as an alternative to a file object opened for name. It is supposed to be at position 0.

so, instead of calling it with positional argument, you can call it with a keyword argument. Pass a fileobj instead of the name.

```
import tarfile

f = open('archive.tar', 'rb')
print (f)
tar = tarfile.open(fileobj=f, mode='r:') # Unpack tar
for item in tar:
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is a way to read the data of each file in the archive:

```
import tarfile

filename = "archive.tar.gz"

with tarfile.open(filename, "r:gz") as file:
    # don't use file.members as it's 
    # not giving nested files and folders
    for member in file:
        # You need additional code to save the data into a list.
        file_content_byte = file.extractfile(member.name).read()
```

If you already know the name of the file in the archive you can do this:

```
import tarfile

filename = "archive.tar.gz"

with tarfile.open(filename, "r:gz") as file:
    file_content_byte = file.extractfile("file.txt").read()
```

Comment: it seems that in recent implementation the loop mustn't be `for member in file.members:` but rather `for member in file:`

Comment: I dont know if they are equivalent (may be point to a doc?), but there are lot of case in Python where this is the case: for line in file / file.readlines(); for key in dict / dict.keys(). I would always choose the more explicit version unless its commonly done otherwise.

Comment: the `... .members:` version would only pull the very first entry of the tar (without gz) for me - which usually is the folder.

Comment: @dothebart You are correct! Thanks for the hint. I updated the code accordingly :)